# Define input files from csv

Tags: snakemake

I would like to define input file names from different varialbles extracted from a csv. I have built the following simplified example:

I have a file test.csv:

```
data/samples/A.fastq
data/samples/B.fastq
```

I give the path to test.csv  in a json config file:

```
{
  "samples": {
    "summaryFile": "somepath/test.csv"
  }
}
```

Now I want to run bwa on each file within a rule. My feeling is that I have to use lambda wildcards but I am not sure. My Snakefile looks like this:

```
#only for bcf_tools

import pandas

input_table = config["samples"]["summaryFile"]
samplesData = pandas.read_csv(input_table)


def returnSamples(table):
  # Have tried different things here but nothing worked
  return table


rule all:
    input:
        expand("mapped_reads/{sample}.bam", sample= samplesData)

rule bwa_map:
    input:
        "data/genome.fa",
        lambda wildcards: returnSamples(wildcards.sample)
    output:
        "mapped_reads/{sample}.bam"
    shell:
        "bwa mem {input} | samtools view -Sb - > {output}"
```

I have tried a million things including using expand (which is working but the rule is not called on each file).

Any help will be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snakemake works by defining which output you want (like you do in `rule all`). You are very close to a working solution, however there were some small things that went wrong:

- Reading the pandas dataframe does not do what you expect (try printing the samplesData to see what it did/does). Therefore the expand in `rule all` does not work properly.
- You do not need to use lambdas for the input, you can reuse the wildcard.

This should work for your example:

```
import pandas
import re

input_table = config["samples"]["summaryFile"]
samplesData = pandas.read_csv(input_table, header=None).loc[:, 0].tolist()
samples = [re.findall("[^/]+\.", sample)[0][:-1] for sample in samplesData]  # overly complicated regex

rule all:
    input:
        expand("mapped_reads/{sample}.bam", sample=samples)

rule bwa_map:
    input:
        "data/genome.fa",
        "data/samples/{sample}.fastq"
    output:
        "mapped_reads/{sample}.bam"
    shell:
        "bwa mem {input} | samtools view -Sb - > {output}"
```

However I think it would be easiest to change the description in `test.csv`. Now we have to do some weird magic to get the sample name from the file, it would probably be best to just store the sample names there.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I need to understand a final thing: How does snakemake relates {sample} to the list "samples"? Could I call it differently?

Comment: Yes, the names are irrelevant. Just usually you have for instance sample and samples since those names are easy to understand. However you could literally call them apples and oranges respectively.